# jQuery Drag & Drop Plugin Effected by BootStrap CSS

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-draggable

I am running into a strange issue where my jQuery Drag & Drop simulation plugin is not working when BootStrap's CSS file is called in the header.

Here are two fiddles with the EXACT same code except for Bootstrap's CSS file being called:

With BootStrap CSS (Doesn't Work):
http://jsfiddle.net/3os4yhen/1/

Without BootStrap CSS (Working):
http://jsfiddle.net/zy3h3doo/1/

Does anyone have any idea what I can disable in that CSS file to keep using in the rest of my page?

Thank you so much!

Here is the full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery Simulate Extended Plugin - jsFiddle demo</title>


<!-- CSS Sheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/gosigner.css">

    <!-- THIS IS WHAT CAUSES THE ISSUE 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap.css"> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/dataTables.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/dropzone.css">


<!-- Global JS Files -->
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body {
        background-color: #EAEAEA;
    }

    #view-port {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 852px;
    }

    .droppableShape {
        z-index: 10;
    }

    #signature-add-canvas {
        background-image: url("/app/img/sign_bg.png");
    }

    .page {
        margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 850px; 
        height:1100px;
        border: 1px solid #DADADA;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="view-port">
            <div id="placeme" class="droppableShape">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6f/Smiley_Face.png" width="25" height="25" />
            </div>
            <button id="testme">Simulate Drop</button>
            <div class="page" id="page1" style="background-image: url(http://images.huffingtonpost.com/2012-08-15-1CanvasPanelInstall5psd.jpg);"></div>
            <!-- Pages Here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


<!-- jQuery UI -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext/jquery.simulate.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext/jquery.simulate.ext.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext/bililiteRange.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext/jquery.simulate.key-sequence.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext/jquery.simulate.key-combo.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://j-ulrich.github.com/jquery-simulate-ext/jquery.simulate.drag-n-drop.js"></script>

<script>

     $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".droppableShape").draggable({
            helper:'clone'
        });

        $(".page").droppable({
            accept: ".droppableShape",
            tolerance: 'fit',
            drop: function(event,ui){
                alert("Drop Detected");
                // Set variables
                var new_field = $(ui.helper).clone().removeClass('droppableShape');
                var droppable_page = $(this);
                var droppableOffset = $(this).offset();
                new_field.css('top', ui.position.top - droppableOffset.top);
                new_field.css('left', ui.position.left - droppableOffset.left);

                // Set Draggable Options
                new_field.draggable({
                    containment: droppable_page,
                    stop: function(event, ui) {
                       // Save position after dragging stops
                       $(this).data("x_cord", ui.position.left);
                       $(this).data("y_cord", ui.position.top);
                    }
                });

                // Add to drop area
                $(this).append(new_field);
            }
        });

        $( "#testme" ).click(function() {
            $('#placeme').simulate("drag-n-drop", {
                dragTarget: $("#page1")
            });
            console.log("Drag Simulated");
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Both of those jsfiddles work for me.

Comment: @DavidG, in both works the Drag & Drop, but only in the one without Bootstrap the *Simulate Drop* button works

Comment: Hey thanks guys, I figured it out. Editing with answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the :

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

..that the bootstrap is giving you.  A quick and easy override is:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: none !important;
box-sizing: none !important;
```

Comment: ..or comment it out, like Nathan suggested.. but I typically don't alter my third party files

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is perfect, I wasn't sure how to override it without commenting it out.

Comment: you'll want to do the same with the -moz-box-sizing, for Firefox

Comment: You're the best! Last question -- right below that code is *:before,
*:after { with the same properties. Should I override those as well?

Comment: I would test it out with those untouched, if it still doesn't work, then yes

Answer (score 1):

I decided to go line-by-line in the bootstrap.css file commenting out styles to see which is affecting the performance:

Line 1068 of bootstrap.css:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

When this is commented out, the Simulate Drop button works